# Using IDL in the command line on mac

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am trying to run a simple IDL program from this website:  https://www.colorado.edu/physics/phys4810/phys4810_sp08/tutorial.htm
here is the code:

```
PRO example
a=5                     ;sets a to 5
b=13.5                  ;and b to 13.5
c=a+b                   ;adds a and b and puts the result in c
d=a*sin(b)              ;sets d to the product of a and Sine(b)
e=b*exp(a)              ;sets e to the product of b and Exp(a)
print,a,b,c,d,e         ;prints the results
END
```

the output should be:

```
5     13.5000     18.5000     4.01892     2003.58
```

however I am getting this:

```
IDL> .run example.pro
% Compiled module: EXAMPLE.
IDL>
```

I have copied the code exactly from the website I linked above and ran it exactly as shown above. I'd like to know where I've gone wrong. Also I am using mac OS 10.13.3 in case that is relevant. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`.run` is for main-level programs, you are trying to call a procedure. You should be able to do just:

```
IDL> example
```